# Post Admin - Filter by posts without tags

Tags: posts, admin, request-filter

I am stuck on this one and it's probably a really simple answer but can anyone please shine some light on how to add a filter menu with an option value of 'No Tags' that when clicking the Filter button will only show posts that have no tags associated with them? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is to add a dropdown using [`restrict_manage_posts`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L221) filter, and the second one is to actually get posts without tags using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter:

```
function wpse147471_add_no_tags_filter() {
    if ( 'post' !== get_current_screen()->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    $selected = ( isset( $_GET['tag-filter'] ) && 'no-tags' === $_GET['tag-filter'] );
    ?>
    <select name="tag-filter">
        <option value="">&mdash; Select &mdash;</option>
        <option value="no-tags" <?php echo selected( $selected ); ?>>No Tags</option>
    </select>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'wpse147471_add_no_tags_filter' );

function wpse147471_get_posts_with_no_tags( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['tag-filter'] ) || 'no-tags' !== $_GET['tag-filter'] ) {
        return;
    }

    $tag_ids = get_terms( 'post_tag', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

    $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $tag_ids,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse147471_get_posts_with_no_tags' );
```

Looks like there is no cleaner way to get all posts without tags via WP_Query than using a `'NOT IN'` taxonomy query with all existing tag IDs, but at least it works.